# .htaccess redirect doesn't work on first load, but does work on refresh

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a rewrite rule that should redirect a user from a pdf to a page on the site. When I go to the url, the pdf loads. However, if I refresh the page, the redirect works.

Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Judy-Special-Report-2.5.pdf$ http://sellinginaskirt.com/outsell [NC,L,R=301]
```

The goal is for http://sellinginaskirt.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Judy-Special-Report-2.5.pdf to redirect to http://sellinginaskirt.com/outsell.

To recreate the issue, go to http://sellinginaskirt.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Judy-Special-Report-2.5.pdf. The PDF loads. Then refresh the page. http://sellinginaskirt.com/outsell loads.

What changes can I make to fix this issue?

I'm experiencing this in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is fine. It redirects for me in every browser.

What's probably happening is that when you click on the link, your browser brings up a cached copy of the PDF. But when you explicitly reload the page, it sends the request to the server instead of pulling up a cached copy of the page and you see the redirect.

If you want to test it again, clear your chrome cache and hit the link again.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense and makes me feel silly. Works now. Thanks!

Comment: @hookedonwinter Caching is great, except when you least expect it.